# TypeError: print_lol() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fh'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `nester.py` file:

```
"""This is the "nester.py" module, and it provides one function called
 print_lol which print lists that may or maynot include nested lists"""
import sys 
def print_lol(the_list, indent=False, level=0, fh=sys.stdout): 
    """This function takes a positional argument called "the_list" which is
    any python list (of , possibly, nested lists). each data item in the provided
    list is (recursively) printed to the screen on its own line.
    A second argument called level is used to insert tab-stops when a nested
    list is encountered"""

    for each_item in the_list: 
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            print_lol(each_item, indent, level+1, fh)

        else:
            if indent:
                for tab_stop in range(level):
                    print("\t", end = "", file=fh)


        print(each_item, file=fh
```

And some actual code that uses it:

```
*************************************************************
# This is my actual code

import nester 

man = []
other = []

try:
    data = open("sketch.txt")
    for each_line in data:
        try:
            (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(":", 1)
            line_spoken = line_spoken.strip()
            if role == "Man":
                man.append(line_spoken)
            elif role == "Other Man":
                other.append(line_spoken)

        except ValueError:
            pass
    data.close()
except IOError:
    print("The data file is missing!")

try:
    with open("man_data.txt", "w") as man_file:
        nester.print_lol(man, fh=man_file)


    with open("other_data.txt", "w") as other_file:
        nester.print_lol(other, fh=other_file)


except IOError as err:
    print("File error: " + str(err))
```

I have seen some posts here in this community, however none of them have helped me to solve this problem. I am new to Python and I have been stuck at this stage for the past four days. I cannot figure it out how to get my function to work.

I dont know whether I have to install some other packages. Without using `nester`, the program works fine even though it is not neat.

Comment: What does `help(nester.print_lol)` output? It looks like you're using a different version of the method. Maybe check which version of the library you have installed vs the version of the source above.

Comment: shaara, your edit appears to have broken the actual code, reverting for now... and fixing up grammar/layout as well :-)

Comment: Thank you  @Carcigenicate. it was helpful as there was some update issue.